# Auto detect for USB Device not working (Garmin Watch)

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount

I would like my Raspberry Pi 3 to auto detect my Garmin watch USB device when connected it via USB to it. So I could copy the `.fit` files from the devices for subsequent processing.

Currently I cannot manage to auto detect the device when connecting it to the Pi.

When connecting the watch to my laptop running Linux Mint it automatically detects the device and mounts the files on the device at the following path

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/Primary/GARMIN/Activity/...`

including all the wanted `.fit` files. Since Mint / Ubuntu as well as Rasbian are based on Debian I hoped it would work, but maybe I am just missing a package which handles this?

Connecting the device to a Mac tells me the connection is established using *MTP*. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I could solve this?

Note: I'm using Raspbian Buster Lite.

The output of `dmesg` after connecting the device is

```
[  354.628053] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  354.758319] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=091e, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  354.758335] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  354.760485] garmin_gps 1-1.2:1.0: Garmin GPS usb/tty converter detected
[  354.761017] usb 1-1.2: Garmin GPS usb/tty converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

**Edit 11.25.2019:**

Additional info: 
using `lsusb` shows the Raspberry Pi somehow detects the device

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 091e:4b48 Garmin International
```

Using the given bus (001) and device (004) and `udevadm` I also get a ton of information about my device

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/001/004 
P: /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
N: bus/usb/001/004
L: 0
S: libmtp-1-1.2
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/004
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
...
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffff00:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Garmin International
E: GPHOTO2_DRIVER=PTP
E: ID_GPHOTO2=1
E: ID_MEDIA_PLAYER=1
E: ID_MTP_DEVICE=1
E: ID_PATH=platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.2
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_2
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_2
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/libmtp-1-1.2
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
```

Adding `udev` rules like described on [this OSM article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/USB_Garmin_on_GNU/Linux) in the section "Fixing Device Permissions" does also not help. I tried it with the following rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-garmin.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4b48", MODE="666"
```

Which contains the vendor and product id given from `lsusb`.

Hope someone knows how to proceed with this.

Comment: Try searching Mint packages (eg. for "garmin") to see what it is.

Comment: I tried installing all packages related to "usb", "gvfs", "mtp" without success. Even Rasbian Full (aka. desktop versoin) does not auto connect the device. Any other hint? @goldilocks

Comment: Try `grep -i garmin /etc/udev/rules.d`; this is almost certainly part of the methodology.  If nothing shows up, eyeball the files that are in there and see if anything looks related (there will just be a few small text files).

Comment: On the RPI there are now files at all in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. On my laptop there is nothing gamrin related with `grep -i garmin /etc/udev/rules.d/*`. I added some more info of what I found so far above. But I still don't manage to mount the device @goldilocks